# Google Visualisation Column Chart aligning legend

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

I am trying to get the legend of the column chart to the top and this is the code I have tried:

```
<div id="{{ question.0.name }}" style="width: 100%; height: 400px;"></div>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['bar']});
            google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

            function drawChart() {
              var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
                ['Rating', 'Survey sent {{form_one.date_created}} ', 'Survey sent {{form_two.date_created}} '],
                ['Very Poor', {{ question.1.0.0}}, {{ question.1.1.0}}],
                ['Poor', {{ question.1.0.1}}, {{ question.1.1.1}}],
                ['Average', {{ question.1.0.2}}, {{ question.1.1.2}}],
                ['Good', {{ question.1.0.3}}, {{ question.1.1.3}}],
                ['Very Good', {{ question.1.0.4}}, {{ question.1.1.4}}]

              ]);

              var options = {
                height: 400,   
                legend: {
                            alignment: 'center',
                            position: 'top'
                        }
              };

              var chart = new google.charts.Bar(document.getElementById('{{ question.0.name }}'));

              chart.draw(data, options);
            }
          </script>
```

It doesn't work. Please advise on how I can get this to work

Answer (score 0):

there are many options that are not supported by *Material* charts, including...

```
legend.alignment
legend.maxLines
legend.position: ['top', 'bottom']
```

see --> [Tracking Issue for Material Chart Feature Parity](https://github.com/google/google-visualization-issues/issues/2143)

*Material* --> `google.charts.Bar` -- `packages:['bar']`

*Classic* --> `google.visualization.BarChart / ColumnChart` -- `packages: ['corechart']`

one option is to use a *Classic* chart, with the following option...

```
theme: 'material'
```

which will style a *Classic* chart **similarly** to a *Material* chart

see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  packages: ['corechart']
}).then(function () {
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['Rating', 'Survey sent 1', 'Survey sent 2'],
    ['Very Poor', 1, 2],
    ['Poor', 3, 4],
    ['Average', 5, 6],
    ['Good', 7, 8],
    ['Very Good', 9, 10]
  ]);

  var options = {
    height: 400,
    legend: {
      alignment: 'center',
      position: 'top'
    },
    theme: 'material'
  };

  var chart = new google.visualization.BarChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
  chart.draw(data, options);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
```